# mock function error in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Hii Everyone I am new to react testing ,I am trying to do some example for practise , I am getting a Error,Need your help  , this is my App Component

```
  const[firstName,setFirstName]=useState("")
  const[lastName,setLastName]=useState("")
  const [data,setData] = useState({})

  const handleFirstName = (e) =>{
    setFirstName(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleLastName = (e) =>{
    setLastName(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setData({firstName,lastName})
    console.log(firstName,lastName)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="form" >
       <div>
         <label>FirstName
         <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value={firstName} onChange={handleFirstName}/>
         </label>
       </div>
       {firstName && firstName.length > 10 && <p data-testid="error-msg" >FirstName is not valid</p>}
       <div>
         <label>lastName
         <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value={lastName} onChange={handleLastName}/>
         </label>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" disabled={firstName === ""} >submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my testing logic

```
  const mockFunction = jest.fn();
  const {getByText}=render(<App onSubmit={mockFunction}/>)
  const firstNameLabel = screen.getByRole("textbox",{'name':'FirstName'})
  fireEvent.change(firstNameLabel,{"target":{'value':"dhffssß"}})
  const lastNameLabel = screen.getByRole("textbox",{"name":"lastName"})
  fireEvent.change(lastNameLabel,{"target":{'value':"dhfffsß"}})
  const btn = screen.getByRole('button',{'name':'submit'})
  fireEvent.click(btn)
  expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
 })
```

I am testing simple form but getting this error

---

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

---

Comment: where you call `onSubmit` function which you pass to `App` as a prop?

Comment: I am calling that function on Form submit in return method

Comment: you calling `handleSubmit` function, but I don't see you calling `onSubmit` somewhere

Comment: can you make changes in current code, if possible . it would be really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `onSubmit` function which you pass in props in your `handleSubmit` handler. In this case you should be able to track if the `onSubmit` callback was called in your tests.

```
const App = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const[firstName,setFirstName]=useState("")
  const[lastName,setLastName]=useState("")
  const [data,setData] = useState({})

  const handleFirstName = (e) =>{
    setFirstName(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleLastName = (e) =>{
    setLastName(e.target.value)
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setData({firstName,lastName});
    console.log(firstName,lastName);
    onSubmit();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="form" >
       <div>
         <label>FirstName
         <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value={firstName} onChange={handleFirstName}/>
         </label>
       </div>
       {firstName && firstName.length > 10 && <p data-testid="error-msg" >FirstName is not valid</p>}
       <div>
         <label>lastName
         <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value={lastName} onChange={handleLastName}/>
         </label>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" disabled={firstName === ""} >submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait until the submit button is enabled before trying to interact with it, after you changed the `firstName` input, and wait for the callback call (not sure the second `wait` is usefull) :

```js
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

const mockFunction = jest.fn();
const {getByText}=render(<App onSubmit={mockFunction}/>)
const firstNameLabel = screen.getByRole("textbox",{'name':'FirstName'})
fireEvent.change(firstNameLabel,{"target":{'value':"dhffssß"}})
const lastNameLabel = screen.getByRole("textbox",{"name":"lastName"})
fireEvent.change(lastNameLabel,{"target":{'value':"dhfffsß"}})

// wait until button is enabled
await waitFor(() => expect(getByText('submit').toBeEnabled());

fireEvent.click(getByText('submit'));
await waitFor(() => expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```